# Cannot sort dates in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to sort my dates by ascending/descending order in jQuery but with no luck. Any idea to what is going wrong? Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/UdwNh/

```
 var itemsArray = $('div#activity_box');
    itemsArray.sort(function(a,b){
        var aTime = new Date($(a).find('#activity_date').text()).getTime();
        var bTime = new Date($(b).find('#activity_date').text()).getTime();
        return aTime - bTime;
    });

    $('#sortAsc').click(function(){
        $("#wrapper").empty();
        $(itemsArray).each(function(){
            $("#wrapper").prepend($(this));
        });
    });

    $('#sortDesc').click(function(){
        $("#wrapper").empty();
        $(itemsArray).each(function(){
            $("#wrapper").append($(this));
        });
    });​
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<input class="btn" type="button" value="Sort Ascending" id="sortAsc"/>
<input class="btn" type="button" value="Sort Descending" id="sortDesc"/>

<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
    <li class='item'><div id='activity_date'>01/10/2012</div>
    <div id='activity_box'>
    <div id='activity_text' class='windowClass2'>...text here...</div>
    </div></li><li class='item'><div id='activity_date'>04/10/2012</div>
    <div id='activity_box'>
    <div id='activity_text' class='windowClass2'>...text here...</div>
    </div></li><li class='item'><div id='activity_date'>10/10/2012</div>
    <div id='activity_box'>
    <div id='activity_text' class='windowClass2'>...text here...</div>
    </div></li><li class='item'><div id='activity_date'>16/10/2012</div>
    <div id='activity_box'>
    <div id='activity_text' class='windowClass2'>...text here...</div>
    </div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Always post the relevant code and markup ***in the question itself***, don't just link.

Comment: ***sigh*** Okay, I've done it for you. But after 278 previous questions, really, you should be doing this yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with that code.

1. You're using the same `id` value on more than one element. [`id` values ***must*** be unique on the page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute).

   To fix it, use a class value instead, or a [`data-*` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes), or anything else that's allowed to occur more than once on a page.
2. You're calling `sort` on a jQuery instance. jQuery [has no documented `sort` function](http://api.jquery.com). It may have an undocumented one, but if so, you have no idea what it does. It's certainly doesn't make sense to assume it will rearrange DOM elements.

   To fix it, you'll have to write your own function for that (it's not complicated), or find a plug-in that does it for you.
3. Even if `sort` did work, the date strings you're passing into `new Date(string)` are in the form `20/10/2012`, `17/10/2012`, and such. That isn't a format that `new Date(string)` is documented to understand. The only string format that [`new Date(string)` is documented to understand](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) is a simplified form of [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which doesn't look like that. And in fact, `new Date("20/10/2012")` fails on Chrome and probably other browsers.

   To fix it, you'll need to get the dates another way. You could store the milliseconds-since-the-Epoch value on the elements as a [`data-*` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) and then use it directly. Or you could parse the date strings you have yourself. If they're always in that `dd/mm/yyyy` format, parsing the individual parts into numbers is trivial, and then you can pass the resulting numbers for the year, month, and day into [`new Date(year, month, date)`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.1). (Remember that months start with `0` = January.)
4. You're putting in a closing `</li>` in at the outset, where there's no opening `<li>`.

   To fix it, don't do that. :-)

Comment: An HTML is here http://jsfiddle.net/UdwNh/ and yes, IDs are duplicated there. Using of CSS class to mark items could be fine in this case.

Comment: Could you show me an example perhaps on jQuery? It still doesn't seem to work http://jsfiddle.net/UdwNh/1/

Comment: @methuselah: Your updated fiddle still uses the same `id` value in more than one place. I can't be more clear: You can't have the same `id` value in more than one place, it simply won't work.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder still no luck > http://jsfiddle.net/UdwNh/2/. Is there anything I'm missing out on?

Comment: @methuselah: Well, you're calling `sort` on a jQuery instance, which is not an array, and jQuery doesn't document a `sort` function. So that's a problem. (There may be an undocumented one -- don't use undocumented functions.) More to the point, your fiddle wasn't loading jQuery, which is kind of going to be a problem from the get-go. So A) Load the library, and B) Use only its documented features, and in particular, note that jQuery doesn't provide a `sort` function that reorders elements.

Comment: I've loaded the library now > http://jsfiddle.net/UdwNh/3/ and based my code on this fiddle here > http://jsfiddle.net/vDN3w/4/

Comment: @methuselah date format is invalid to pass to Date object. Log your dates to console will see they aren't calculated to what you want them to be

Comment: @methuselah: You're still calling an undocumented function. Did you even read my comment above? I've updated the answer to list the biggest issues with that code, and how to fix them. Hope that helps.